# Cyclic dependency between Type A and B

Tags: java, oop, orm, relational-database

I have two classes:

```
class A {

    final B b;

    A(final B b) {
    this.b = b;
    }

    void doIt() {
    b.doSomething();
    }

    void doSomething() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

and

```
class B {

    final A a;

    B(final A a) {
    this.a = a;
    }

    void doIt() {
    a.doSomething();
    }

    void doSomething() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

There is no way to instantiate any of them.

I could use a setter, e.g:

```
class B {

    A a;

    B() {

    }

    void setA(final A a) {
    this.a = a;
    }

    void doIt() {
    a.doSomething();
    }

    void doSomething() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

But here I need checking for `a` being `null` in `doIt()` and handling this case. This is not the end of the world, but maybe

**there is a more clever way to do it?**

Or maybe this is even an **anti pattern** in general and something is wrong with the architecture in the first place?

**Root of the problem**:

I have a database from which I load entities. I cache them once loaded and use this cache to establish **bi-directional relationships** between the types. This is necessary, since when I load multiple instances of `A`, they should have (in this case) all the same instance of `B`. Therefore B needs to be instantiated before and re-used. But `B` has also a relationship to all these `a`s, therefore the cyclic dependency.

So in more short, **The cyclic dependencies are caused by bi-directional relationships in the database**. I use to avoid them where possible but besides of the trouble described here, there is no 'real-world' problem with bi-di relationships, in fact it is a very natural thing.

So maybe the question should be **How to properly map bi-di-relationships from a relational database into the oop world?**

**More concrete example:**

To establish bi-di relationships, I load instances from a cache, so that I have the same instance when the entity ID is the same:

```
interface Cache<T>

interface CacheA extends Cache<A>

interface CacheB extends Cache<B>

class CacheManager {

    final CacheA cacheA;

    final CacheB cacheB;

    CacheManager(final DatabaseAccess databaseAccess) {
    cachA = new CacheA();
    cachB = new CacheB();
    cacheA.setEntityLoader(id -> new SimpleAttachedA(id, databaseAccess, cacheB));
    cacheB.setEntityLoader(id -> new SimpleAttachedB(id, databaseAccess, cacheA));

    }

}
```

Instances of `A` will access this cache if the relationship to `B` is accessed. The same the other way around.

I know that it would be best, if `CacheA` and `CacheB` would be the same object, since then I could just create the cache and pass it on to all instances of `A` and `B`.

`CacheA` and `CacheB` used to be the same, namely `Cache`. I chose to separate those, so I can use a generic class and remove a lot of duplicate code.

`CacheManager` cannot implement `CacheA` and `CacheB`, if they both extend the same generic interface `Cache<T>` but with different types of `T`.

Therefore `CacheManager` uses composition instead of inheritance. So I end up with two caches, which need to access each other to realize the bi-di relationship of `A` and `B`.

Answer (score 2):

Cyclic dependencies are typically a sign of bad design. In some cases you cannot prevent cyclic dependencies, but you should always think about another solution. When you have cyclic depedencies, chances are that you will change one of the classes and have to change the other one as well. When your cycle contains more than two classes, this can be a lot of work. Also problems like the one you mentioned, "I need the other class to instantiate one of them", arise.

As your classes appear to be dummy classes, I cannot give a really good advise, but some general points nonetheless.

Classes should have **high cohesion** and **low coupling**. Meaning, classes should depend on another as less as possible (low coupling), while every class should do one functionality, and all of that functionality (high cohesion).

When you have two classes which depend on one another, this is typically a sign for low cohesion, as part of the functionality is in class `A` and another part in class `B`. In this case you should consider merging both classes in one class.

On the other hand when you try to find a class name for that merged class and come up with something like `ThisAndThatDoer`, you should split them in two classes `ThisDoer` and `ThatDoer`, as this is a sign for low cohesion. When you then have your original classes depending on one another again, you could maybe create a new class `Executor` which connects both classes. But this can quickly become a *god class*, which is also an anti-pattern. So you should be careful with this.

So all in all, I recommend thinking about your class design and finding a way to remove the depedency at least in one direction. I hope this helps with your problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed considered an anti-pattern and often, there is a better way to do it. If `A` needs `B` and B needs A this suggests that

- functionality, which conceptually belongs together, is divided into two components (A and B). Because each component only implements part of the functionality, it needs the other to do what's missing. *Solution:* Identify the parts of A and B that belong together and move them to a new component C. Make what's left of A and B depend on C and remove the dependencies between A and B.
- A contains two separate functionalities A1 and A2 that could be divided into two separate components. If A1 needs functionality provided by B and B needs functionality provided by A1, a circular dependency between A and B results. *Solution:* Split A into two separate components A1 and A2 and make A1 depend on B and make B depend on A2.

As mentioned earlier, there are cases where circular dependencies are alright and would result in a more obscure design if avoided. However, often this is not the case and you should try to restructure your functionalities to avoid circular dependencies.

If you provide more info on your specific case (i.e. what are A and B doing and what are the parts that depend on each other), more tips can be given.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, please see edited question for some more concrete explanation of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

> Or maybe this is even an anti pattern in general and something is
>   wrong with the architecture in the first place?

1) A bidirectional coupling between two concrete classes should be avoided as much as possible if both classes don't need  to have access all members of the other class.
Make it generally creates a coupling higher than needed.

2) A bidirectional coupling is not necessary a problem if it is required but a cyclic dependency in the construction of the objects is.
**It is a bad smell as it is not solvable without breaking it.**

Your solution with a setter is indeed a way to solve it.
If you want really to avoid it and keep the constructors way in both classes, you have some solutions if you change your design.

You could for example replace one of both parameter (A or B class)  by a class that will contain all data to create the `A` or  `B` instance.

Suppose you want to abstract the creation of `B` :

**A**

```
public A(ContextForB contextForB) {
    // init A data
      ...
    // create B from context and set the B dependency
    b = new B(contextForB, this);
}
```

**B**

```
public B(ContextForB contextForB, A a) {
   //.. create B from the context
      ...
   // set the A dependency
   this.a = a;
}
```

`ContextForB` can be anything.
`ResultSet`, `Query`, `Iterator`, `Supplier` etc...

You can so use them in these ways :

```
// instantiate both from A
A a = new A(new ContextForB(...));  

// OR instantiate both from B
ContextForB contextForB = new ContextForB(...);
B b = new B(contextForB, new A(contextForB));
```

Comment: Thanks for the excellent answer! I think I will just use a setter ;) Nevertheless, I edited the question to illustrate the problem more concretely, since A and B do not depend on each other actually, and they are not concrete types either. Maybe you could also comment on the more detailed description of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Create interface

```
public interface Doable {
      void doSomething();
}
```

Then use it in A and B:

```
class A implements Doable {

    final Doable b;

    A(final Doable b) {
    this.b = b;
    }

    void doIt() {
    b.doSomething();
    }

    @Override
    void doSomething() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

and

```
class B implements Doable {

    Doable a;

    B(final Doable a) {
      this.a = a;
    }

    void doIt() {
    a.doSomething();
    }
    @Override
    void doSomething() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

Here you will avoid cyclic dependency.

Comment: I still need in A and B an instance of Doable. The only difference here is that I could give A also an instance of A instead of B, since both implement the same interface. This was also only an example, for a more concrete explanation of the problem please see the edited question.

Comment: kerner1000, I think my answer is suitable to the edited question. You can create separate interfaces for A and B and then use them in each other.

Comment: Sorry, but I think this does not work. Were does the instance of Doable come from? I cannot instantiate any implementing class of Doable.